# Android ListView click to new Activity

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-listview

My application take barcode id of product and give back markets with prices where have that product.
In listview I have markets and prices.
When i click listview elements i want to proceed with new activity where market details should print to textview or something..
However when i click element, emulator crashes like "unfortunately stopped"

Here my java code, php code and log;
(i took barcode from previous activity and sending market name to next activity to do necessary json, php, db queries)

```
public class Query_product extends ListActivity {

    JSONArray products = null;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    String pid;
    String market;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    // url to get all products list
    private static final String url_market = "http://furkan.feramor.gen.tr/webservice/enucuz.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "barcode";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_MARKET = "mname";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray product = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        pid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.ID);

        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
            //  String mName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.marketName)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , Market_details.class);

                in.putExtra("market", market);
                Log.d("aaaaaa",market);
                // starting new activity 
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });


    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Query_product.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            // getting JSON string from URL

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_market, "GET", params1);

            // Log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());


            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        market = c.getString(TAG_MARKET);

                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
   ////////             String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MARKET, market);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            menu.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Query_product.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_MARKET, TAG_PRICE  },  new int[] {R.id.marketName, R.id.price  });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

php:

```
<?php



// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
if (isset($_GET["barcode"])) {
    $barcode = $_GET['barcode'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, markets.mname 
                FROM products 
                INNER JOIN markets ON products.marketid = markets.marketid 
                WHERE barcode = '$barcode'  
                ORDER BY price") or die (mysql_error());


// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["barcode"] = $row["barcode"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["description"] = $row["description"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        $product["mname"]= $row["mname"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

market details java class:

```
public class Market_details extends Activity {

    TextView txtMarketName, txtMarketLoc;
    JSONArray markets = null;
    String marketName;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_market_details = "http://furkan.feramor.gen.tr/webservice/marketinfo.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_MARKET = "mname";
    private static final String TAG_MARKETLOC = "mloc";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.market_detail);

        // getting market name from intent
        marketName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("market");
        Log.d("bbbbbbb",marketName);




        // Getting market details in background thread
        new GetMarketDetails().execute();


    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetMarketDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("CCC","A");
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Market_details.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading market details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            Log.d("DDD","");

        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.d("EEE","");

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mname", marketName));
                        Log.d("FFF","");
                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_market_details, "GET", params);
                        Log.d("GGG","");
                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Market Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            Log.d("HHHH","");
                            markets = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                            for (int i = 0; i < markets.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = markets.getJSONObject(i);

                            String marketname = c.getString(TAG_MARKET);
                            String marketloc = c.getString(TAG_MARKETLOC);

                            Log.d("ccccccc",marketname);
                            txtMarketName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marketname);
                            txtMarketLoc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marketloc);

                            txtMarketName.setText(marketname);
                            txtMarketLoc.setText(marketloc);
                            Log.d("KKKK","");
                            }
                        }else{


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

here merketinfo.php:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single market details
 * A market is identified by market id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_POST["mname"])) {
    $mname= $_POST['mname'];

    // get a market from markets table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markets WHERE mname = '$mname");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $market = array();
            $market["marketid"] = $result["marketid"];
            $market["mname"] = $result["mname"];
            $market["mtelno"] = $result["mtelno"];
            $market["mloc"] = $result["mloc"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["market"] = array();

            array_push($response["markets"], $market);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            // no market found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No market found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no market found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No market found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

here my log:

```
12-24 17:17:15.783: D/libEGL(832): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-24 17:17:15.793: D/(832): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1dce88, tid 832
12-24 17:17:15.853: D/libEGL(832): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-24 17:17:15.873: D/libEGL(832): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
12-24 17:17:15.973: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:17:15.993: D/OpenGLRenderer(832): Enabling debug mode 0
12-24 17:32:12.384: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:32:39.856: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:32:40.604: D/dalvikvm(832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 8% free 2946K/3176K, paused 293ms, total 394ms
12-24 17:32:46.194: D/dalvikvm(832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 6% free 3107K/3304K, paused 71ms, total 97ms
12-24 17:32:46.223: I/dalvikvm-heap(832): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.260MB for 1127536-byte allocation
12-24 17:32:46.393: D/dalvikvm(832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 4206K/4408K, paused 162ms, total 162ms
12-24 17:32:47.024: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:32:47.376: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:32:47.603: I/Choreographer(832): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 17:32:48.414: I/Choreographer(832): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-24 17:32:53.764: D/All Products:(832): {"success":1,"products":[{"mname":"KAS","created_at":"2013-12-24 14:17:13","barcode":"12345","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","price":"2.00","description":"iyi","name":"mete"}]}
12-24 17:32:58.234: D/aaaaaa(832): KAS
12-24 17:32:59.014: D/bbbbbbb(832): KAS
12-24 17:32:59.024: D/CCC(832): A
12-24 17:32:59.683: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:33:00.404: W/EGL_emulation(832): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:33:00.923: D/AndroidRuntime(832): Shutting down VM
12-24 17:33:00.923: W/dalvikvm(832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.example.ssa.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.example.ssa.Market_details$GetMarketDetails$1.run(Market_details.java:102)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-24 17:33:01.586: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 17:33:01.924: D/dalvikvm(832): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 7% free 4602K/4932K, paused 277ms, total 296ms
12-24 17:33:09.916: D/libEGL(871): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-24 17:33:10.089: D/(871): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1e0260, tid 871
12-24 17:33:10.164: D/libEGL(871): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-24 17:33:10.184: D/libEGL(871): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
12-24 17:33:10.416: W/EGL_emulation(871): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-24 17:33:10.435: D/OpenGLRenderer(871): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be calling `runOnUiThread` in your `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` method, this is in your `Market_details`.

I would do all the heavy network stuff in `doInBackground` and update the UI in the post method instead.

Comment: Yes now activity succsessfuly came. However textviews are empty :/ Like this: Market Name: (EMPTY) Market Location: (EMPTY)

Comment: Not really sure without debugging your code but I would try to pass `markets = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);` from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute`. Do all your layout updates there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Market details class where :
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

```
        Log.d("EEE","");

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mname", marketName));
                    Log.d("FFF","");
                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_market_details, "GET", params);
                    Log.d("GGG","");
```

... and so on. 
the reason you use doInBackground is to make network calls in background thread, however you call runOnUIThread which causes networkonmainthread exception. You cannot do network (which is jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_market_details, "GET", params); function call in this case) on UI thread just remove runOnUI part and move all code inside doInBackground

Comment: Yes now activity succsessfuly came. However textviews are empty :/
Like this:
Market Name:
(EMPTY)
Market Location:
(EMPTY)